# Remove blue navigation bar in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation

I have a Sharepoint online page on which I would like to remove the blue navigation bar at the very top of the screen (the one with the seach bar in the middle and the button on the left with 9 dots to switch to different Microsoft apps).

I have checked all of the header settings and also went into the site settings and modified the search settings. I was able to exclude the site from search results, however the blue bar still remains.

Is this possible to remove in a default SharePoint online site without using custom CSS or anything like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not supported and if you do go forward with it, your solution will break over time as Microsoft makes changes to the DOM.

https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/portal-branding#what-not-to-do